# Fit Panel Height to Label Height

Tags: c#, winforms

I have panels and each of them has 1 label. Everything works fine except 1 thing: 
I can't fit the Panel Height to the Label Height...

I'm using this code:

```
        Point location = new Point(0, 0);
        ColorConverter cc = new ColorConverter();

        foreach (var item in temp)
        {
            Panel pan = new Panel();
            pan.AutoSize = false;
            pan.Width = this.Width-75;
            pan.Location = location;
            pan.BackColor = (Color)cc.ConvertFromString("#" + item.Item3);
            Label lbl = new Label();
            lbl.Font = new Font("Arial", 12);
            lbl.ForeColor = Color.White;
            lbl.Text = item.Item2;
            lbl.AutoSize = true;
            lbl.MaximumSize = new Size(pan.Width - 5, 0);
            lbl.Width = pan.Width - 10;
            lbl.Location = new Point(lbl.Location.X + 5, lbl.Location.Y + 5);
            //pan.Height = lbl.Height + 5;
            pan.Controls.Add(lbl);
            flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(pan);
            location = new Point(location.X - pan.Height, location.Y);
        }
```

I tried doing this:

```
pan.Height = lbl.Height + 5;
```

But it the panel is then way too small...

Comment: Hard to see the point of using a panel at all.  Just don't and you don't have to solve this problem.

Comment: @HansPassant I need one

Comment: You could try docking the label in the panel, set the panel AutoSize to true and set AutoSizeMode to GrowAndShrink.  Then you can set the panel padding to 5.  That way you won't have to worry about the label size or location.

Comment: @KiNeTiC I have no clue how to do that xD

Comment: I don't see you setting the panel height. It is hard to say what you are trying to achieve. Please explain what you goal is.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes it's the line at the bottom of my post. I removed it cause it didnt work

Comment: @user6224954 read my answer.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me, that you are using a panel in order to get a margin around the label within the FlowLayoutPanel. If this is the case, set the Label's margin instead and don't use a Panel:

```
lbl.Margin = new Padding(5, 5, 80, 5);
```

or

```
lbl.Margin = new Padding(5); // If all margins are equal
```

the constructors are declared like this

```
public Padding(int left, int top, int right, int bottom)

public Padding(int all)
```

Comment: Or just 
`new Padding(5)`
if left, top, right and bottom are all equal.

Answer (score 0):

You could try docking the label in the panel, set the panel AutoSize to true and set AutoSizeMode to GrowAndShrink. Then you can set the panel padding to 5. That way you won't have to worry about the label size or location

```
foreach (var item in temp)
{
    Panel pan = new Panel();
    pan.Padding = new Padding(5);
    pan.AutoSize = true;
    pan.AutoSizeMode = AutoSizeMode.GrowAndShrink;
    pan.BackColor = (Color)cc.ConvertFromString("#" + item.Item3);
    Label lbl = new Label();
    lbl.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
    lbl.Font = new Font("Arial", 12);
    lbl.ForeColor = Color.White;
    lbl.Text = item.Item2;
    lbl.AutoSize = true;
    lbl.MaximumSize = new Size(pan.Width - 5, 0);
    pan.Controls.Add(lbl);
    flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(pan);
    location = new Point(location.X - pan.Height, location.Y);
}
```

Edit : forgot the padding.

Comment: Which line "docks" the label to the panel? Edit: Nevermind you edited

Comment: It was missing both the padding and the docking lines.  I've added both to my answer.

Comment: Why have you commented the 2 lines? if i do that aswell it makes a lot small cubes. Also, how can i set the panel width to something fixed if it is autosize?

Comment: This is just an example, you can add the commented line back if it fits your needs.

Comment: thanks! but how do i fix now the problem with the width? xD

Comment: Remove the lbl.MaximumSize line.

Comment: Btw, i think the panel is useless as well and that Olivier's answer is the way to go.

Comment: Yes, this is a typical [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @KiNeTiC but that's wrong. it will let the label move out of the form + the panel itself isnt fixed.

Comment: I want the PANEL-WIDTH to be Form.Width-10

Comment: Why don't you dock the FlowLayoutPanel in the form?

Comment: Or is this PANEL the panel you're creating in the foreach?  Are you trying to get one panel per line?

Comment: I really wish I knew what you are trying to accomplish.